# How to do URL decoding in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to unescape this string "Selby%2C%20SD" so the result would be "Selby, SD" (I assume) but can't find the way.

I've tried

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("Selby%2C%20SD")
```

but the result is the same string. I've also tried StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml but didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use URLDecoder in java.net.URLDecoder;

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String tempStr = "Selby%2C%20SD";
        System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(tempStr, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Selby, SD
```